# How do I find the welcome screen in VS Code after I've closed it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, interface

VS Code doesn't seem to look quite the same as in the intro video I watched. The Welcome screen doesn't show the 'Customise' or 'Help' sections shown in the video that I watched... how do I get those?

How do I find the Welcome tab once it has disappeared? How do I collapse the left sidebar?

Comment: You will often find outdated videos of Visual Studio Code tutorials now a days, since the editor has come a long way since it's been created.  Even their own documentation has outdated screenshots/information I've found.

Comment: One of the massive downsides of auto-updating software (especially by Microsoft)... you can never expect the UI to be/work the same as it did yesterday.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse the left sidebar by pressing whatever tab you have open again. For example, if you have the first tab (Explorer) open, you can press that tab again and the bar will collapse. The Welcome screen is found in Help and then first option is "Welcome". I checked it now and it is still there. The Welcome screen has changed a bit if you are watching an older video about Visual Studio Code, so maybe its not the same one for you.

Comment: The shortcut CTRL + B also collapses the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded and installed vscode. (12/22/21)

- I found that you can open and close the Explorer window (left sidebar) by clicking the Explorer button. [Explorer Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mKRc.png)
- The "Welcome" screen is now called "Get Started" and is listed first in the Help menu.